# problems with hibernate saving in database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I'm having a problem with hibernate, the problem is when I save in the database but when I try find this last insertion he don't find until I made some action in database, like I find or erase other data .

This is how I save:

```
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(o);
        session.saveOrUpdate(o1); // o and o1 are two differents objects
        tx.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
    }
```

And this is how I try to find in database after an insertion:

```
 public List getUserNames(int startID, int endID) {
    List<User> userList = null;
    try {
        org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query q = session.createQuery("select u from User u ");
        userList = (List<User>) q.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return userList;
}
```

I tried a lot of things but nothing make difference, like change saveOrUpdate to merge or just save, but didn't made any difference change this things.
thanks for anyone who can help.

Comment: try print the exception in your save function to see if the save gives any errors

Comment: You are sharing the `session` across the two methods? Is it a member of the class that hosts the two methods (which would be bad)? Is this for a single thread or more?

Comment: my save don't have any errors , my insertion works , when I go to  database terminal to show this last insertion , he appears normally, but when i try to find him , he don't find

Comment: sorry @MarcelStör i don't know if I understand your question, but my insert method is in a class, and my search is in another

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but Hibernate doesn't execute the query until you start iterating the result (In your case userList).

Try to iterate userList before closing session.

See example here: [Hibernate Query Language, Using HQL Select Query](http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/part-4-hibernate-query-language-using-hql-select-query/)

Comment: I tried do this now, but didn't work, after I did this, my login page doesn't worked more

Answer (score 0):

Try `refreshing` the state of the session before saving the data to the database http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html#refresh(java.lang.Object). This is generally not recommended as it has its own consequences of not saving the data which the session object has previously acquired. Your stacktrace will be helpful to provide an apt solution.

Comment: i tried this too and how you had said, I can't insert anymore